# Suggest how to use scp and ssh command in ansible with shell or command moudle, also unable to run the scp command from shell script

Tags: ansible

Below is the code i need to run using ansible -
I need to include the scp and ssh command in shell module, is it possible?
The list file contains the ip address of the server where we need to copy the files.
How can i include the following part of code in my playbook.

```
for i in `cat /tmp/list`
    do 
    echo $i
    scp HLC_auth $i:.ssh/authorized_keys
    scp known_hosts.LLC $i:.ssh/known_hosts
    ssh $i "rm -rf .ssh/id_dsa*"
    ssh $i "ssh-keygen -d"
    done
```

I am successfully able to perform the for loop task as below -

```
   shell: for i in `cat /home/dp794d/temp/list`;
            do echo $i;
            done
```

This gives me the list of ip, but when i try to include the scp command under the same, it do not works.

I thought to dump all this code in the script and try to run the script, but still it is giving me some error -

For testing purpose i created one script having an scp command -

My script file(abc.sh) contains below scp command -

!/bin/bash

scp /home/capio/ansible/pmossWipm/day1/playbooks/xyz.txt abc@130.6.50.131:/home/user

My yml looks like -

```
---
- hosts: testserver
  tasks:

   - name: "run the script"
     script: /home/capio/ansible/pmossWipm/day1/scripts/abc.sh
```

But still it is not working , it do not give any response. we need to terminate it.- 
[Playbook error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45v4e.jpg)

Comment: This is not the way you should use Ansible, convert this shell-script into playbook with Ansible modules.

Answer (score 0):

Using your for-loop as the basis for an Ansible playbook...

1. Define an inventory file using your "/tmp/list" file.
2. For each of the "scp" lines, use the Ansible "copy" module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html
3. For the "rm" line, use the Ansible "file" module pointing to the id_dsa files and setting the "state" to "absent": http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html
4. I'm not sure what "ssh-keygen -d" does, but it's probably something that can be done with a pure Ansible module.